# How to validate values that must be integer, non negative, non decimal and not a string? (Or an alphabetic word) from an InputQuery?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Im using an InputQuery to capture a value from the user, but it has to be only an integer `(from 1 to 9999999...)`, not a decimal and not a string (not `ABCDEF`) or not Alphanumeric (`A1B2C3`) and not special chards (`Hi!,`). In delphi `RAD STUDIO 2010.

The scope is to capture the value and then show a message telling the user he has to input only valid values if so.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please note that your description of the input format can be greatly simplified: Indeed, if `s` is a string which is a standard-form integer, then it isn't "decimal" and not ... some non-integer string (including an English or Greek or Russian word). Also note that 1, 2, 3, ... are the *positive* integers, -1, -2, -3, ... the *negative* integers, and 0 is neither positive nor negative. 0, 1, 2, 3, ... are called the *non-negative* integers.

Comment: What component are you using for your user to enter the value into? If it is TEdit then you can set its property `NumbersOnly` to prevent them from typing any other but numerical characters into the edit control in the first place. It even shows the default OS message about trying to type in unsupported characters into the edit box. So then you would only have to check that `EditBox` is not empty or it doesn't contain `0` since when `NumbersOnly` property is set to true users can't even input a negative sign.

Comment: @SilverWarior: The OP said they are using the [`InputQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) function, so it is a standard `TEdit`. Of course, in Delphi 10.4.2, you can use the new [`TNumberBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Using_VCL_TNumberBox_Control) control as well (or my [multi input box](https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/multiinput/readme.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy:

```pascal
var
  s: string;
  i: Integer;
begin

  if InputQuery(Caption, 'Please enter a positive integer:', s) then
    if TryStrToInt(s, i) and (i > 0) then
      ShowMessage('An excellent choice, sir!')
    else
      ShowMessage('That''s not a positive integer, is it?')
```

This will display the prompt and do nothing if the user cancels it (that's expected). On the other hand, if the user does enter a value, it is verified using [`TryStrToInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TryStrToInt) and a simple sign test.

Notice that, due to boolean short-circuit evaluation, the second conjunct (`i > 0`) will only evaluate if the first conjunct (`TryStrToInt(s, i)`) evaluates to `True`, so we will never test an uninitialized variable `i` (not that it would matter in this case, though).

You may also want to use [a more sophisticated input box](https://specials.rejbrand.se/dev/classes/multiinput/readme.html) that automatically validates the input within the dialog itself (disclaimer: my site).

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`InputQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Dialogs.InputQuery) function's own validation feature, which will validate the input when the user clicks OK:

```pascal
var
  s: array of string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(s, 1);
  if InputQuery(Caption, ['Please enter a positive integer:'], s,
    function(const Values: array of string): Boolean
    begin
      Result := (Length(Values) = 1) and TryStrToInt(Values[0], i) and (i > 0);
      if not Result then
        ShowMessage('That''s not a positive integer, is it?')
    end)
  then
    ShowMessageFmt('You chose %d. That''s an excellent choice, sir!', [i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your repply, so in this case the variable i, isn't relevevant but only for filling the second parameter of the TryStrToInt method?

Comment: @BaldwinIV: Did you read the documentation for the `TryStrToInt` function? You should *always* read the documentation for every new function you use in any programming language. `TryStrToInt(s, i)` returns `True` iff `s` can be parsed as an integer. If so, `i` receives this parsed value. So you probably want to use `i` -- otherwise you wouldn't have asked the user for an integer!

Comment: I got it, you're using the converted String s to evaluate on the next condition and to keep the right integer value needed, thank you so much! I will see your input box

Comment: Just a small enhancement, since you're never going to use negative values. You can use StrToUInt and i:Cardinal (or LongWord) - then you don't need to check i>0 and you can accept values from 0 til 4bill instead of 0 to 2bill (apprx.).

Comment: @HeartWare: The OP said that they only want *positive* numbers ("from 1 to 9999999...") in the Q body and "non negative" in the Q title. These are conflicting. Assuming that the OP really does only want 1, 2, 3, ... (positive numbers), you still need the `i > 0` check to handle `0`, which is a perfectly valid `Cardinal`.

Comment: Good point, @AndreasRejbrand. I had overlooked the mention of "from 1 to 9999999" and focused on the "non-negative" (which includes zero). So if zero is an invalid integer in this context, you'd need the "i>0", and if you don't need above 2bill, you can get by with an integer instead of a cardinal.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I agree with HeartWaare suggestion about using of `TryStrToUInt` and using of untyped integer types in order to reduce the chance of integer overflow that happen when you pas a string representing number greater than `2147483647` to TryStrToint function and thus result in negative number. TO be honest I'm shocked on how often programmers use typed integers variables even thou they never plan for their value to be negative. And then when integer overflow happens they are wondering why their program doesn't exhibit the expected behavior or causes any exception.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Surely you mean *unsigned*, not *untyped*. And surely you know that unsigned integers also can overflow. Regarding the "unmotivated" use of signed integers, that's probably because `Integer` is the "standard" Integer type. For instance, in VCL, you'll find that `TControl.Width` is an `Integer` even though a control's width rarely is negative.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes I meant unsigned not untyped. And yes I know that even with unsigned integer types you can end up with integer overflow. That is why I have written _reduce the chance of integer overflow_ and not _prevent integer overflow_.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand As for why VCL declares their component `Width` property as integer and not UInt since negative width isn't logical in the first place. I would bet that main motivation for this is the fact that programmers often use `Width` in combination with positional properties that do need to be stored as typed integers as they are expected to also have negative values in various calculations in order to avoid the need of changing untyped to typed integers for every such calculation as this would cause additional overhead and thus lower the performance of such calculations.

Comment: @SilverWarior: And then what makes you think the OP won't use their number in such calculations? :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Nothing makes me think that OP won't be using their number in such calculation. But that doesn't make my suggestion for using unsigned integers a bad suggestion. In the end OP has best chance to chose most efficient way for him if he is made aware of all of the options that are available for him.